# Inserting into a Table joined to another Table by a reference table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I came up with this database design after discussing it with many people over IRC.
[image]

In my project, a User aka Member can have many "Teams" & "Projects" on his account and can  be part of some "Projects" as well. Moreover, "Teams" can have many "Members" as well including the Member who is creating it.

Now my question is, suppose, a Member wants to create a Project or a Team **under** his account (later on I want to see all projects created by a specific member), can I do a insert into the using following in PHP?

`INSERT INTO projects VALUES(values) WHERE member_id = something`

I can get the member_id using the session variable I guess.

Comment: You are looking for mysql_insert_id() to get project id add by Member, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Use regular `INSERT` to create the `projects` or `teams` row, then use the ID created there to insert into the `projects_members` or `teams_members`. Also settle on plural or singular names for your tables (currently you have `team` not `teams`).

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be somethings like this

```
Insert into 
       table(columns) 
select (columns) from 
       another_table 
where 
       conditions=.
```

Just Remember One thing the order and names of columns must match.

Answer (score 0):

If Member wants to create a Project or a Team under his account it will not be possible using current structure.

You need to add one more column created_by on projects and team tables.

The name of "team" table should be "teams".

Comment: `created_by` will be a foreign key right? Then how will I do the insert?

Comment: yes it will be referencing to membet_id of member table. INSERT INTO projects VALUES(comma separated values)