# Selecting from two tables joined by a reference table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a tough time figuring everything out & this question follows from this question, [Inserting into a Table joined to another Table by a reference table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041135/inserting-into-a-table-joined-to-another-table-by-a-reference-table).

Well half of what I am trying to do is explained in that question, some other things I am trying to do will be explained in this one.

I have this data in Teams table (can be a Projects Table as well) and Members table

```
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| team_id | team_name           | team_desc            |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
|       1 | Toronto Maple Leafs | Team is Awesome!     |
|       2 | Vancouver Kanucks   | Team Sucks!          |
|       3 | Chicago Bulls       | Team is Fine!        |
|       4 | New York Boys       | Nah! It doesn't suck |
+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

and this data in Members table

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| member_id | firstname | lastname | address                         | state         | country     | email                         | phone      | experience | designation | username | password        |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|         1 | Duncan    | Daniel   | P.O. Box 470, 2775 Ac Road      | NS            | Israel      | duncan@aol.in                 | 9288091790 | 1          | Script      | duncan   | debbyisaweseome |
|         2 | Ivan      | Richmond | P.O. Box 797, 906 Cursus Street | New Brunswick | Timor-Leste | ligula.tortor.dictum@Duis.com | 8087179788 | 5          | Storyboard  | ivan     | ivaniscool      |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
```

and these two tables are joined by this teams_members table,

```
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| teams_members_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| teams_id         | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| members_id       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see `teams_id` & `members_id` are Foreign keys from teams & members.

Now as suggested in the upvoted post in mentioned question, I first inserted a row into teams and then into team_members table like this,

```
INSERT INTO teams(`team_name`,`team_desc`) values ("New York Boys", "Nah! It doesn't suck");
INSERT INTO teams_members (`members_id`,`teams_id`) VALUES
((SELECT member_id from members WHERE member_id = 2),
(SELECT team_id from teams WHERE team_name = "New York Boys"))
```

And then tried to select for the team created by a specific member like this,

```
SELECT * FROM teams_members, members, teams WHERE members_id = member_id && member_id = 1;
```

But instead of showing just one team, it gave me this result:

```
+------------------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+-------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
| teams_members_id | teams_id | members_id | member_id | firstname | lastname | address                    | state | country | email         | phone      | experience | designation | username | password        | team_id | team_name           | team_desc            |
+------------------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+-------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
|                1 |        3 |          1 |         1 | Duncan    | Daniel   | P.O. Box 470, 2775 Ac Road | NS    | Israel  | duncan@aol.in | 9288091790 | 1          | Script      | duncan   | debbyisaweseome |       1 | Toronto Maple Leafs | Team is Awesome!     |
|                1 |        3 |          1 |         1 | Duncan    | Daniel   | P.O. Box 470, 2775 Ac Road | NS    | Israel  | duncan@aol.in | 9288091790 | 1          | Script      | duncan   | debbyisaweseome |       2 | Vancouver Kanucks   | Team Sucks!          |
|                1 |        3 |          1 |         1 | Duncan    | Daniel   | P.O. Box 470, 2775 Ac Road | NS    | Israel  | duncan@aol.in | 9288091790 | 1          | Script      | duncan   | debbyisaweseome |       3 | Chicago Bulls       | Team is Fine!        |
|                1 |        3 |          1 |         1 | Duncan    | Daniel   | P.O. Box 470, 2775 Ac Road | NS    | Israel  | duncan@aol.in | 9288091790 | 1          | Script      | duncan   | debbyisaweseome |       4 | New York Boys       | Nah! It doesn't suck |
+------------------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+-------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Is there something I was missing in my query? Moreover, regarding the insert part, is there any better way to do that?

Comment: You'll want to look at joins for this: your query is getting repeated results as the product of all rows is made.

Comment: You can also shorten the insert statement to 

`INSERT INTO teams(team_name,team_desc) values ("New York Boys", "Nah! It doesn't suck");`; get the id of the new record using e.g. `mysqli_last_insert_id` and stick it in a variable, then `INSERT INTO teams_members (members_id,teams_id) VALUES(2, $team_id)`.

Comment: @user1601973 Why is it `member*s*_id` and `team*s*_id` and not `member_id` and `team_id`? Also what's the point of the `teams_members_id` column? Oh, and tables have `columns`, not `fields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM teams_members tm, members m, teams t 
WHERE tm.members_id = m.member_id 
AND m.member_id = 1
AND tm.teams_id = t.team_id
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Replace * with columns you would like to fetch.

2) Add aliases for tables: ... FROM teams_members tm, members m, teams t where ...

3) use fields with aliases tables in where: m.member_id = tm.member_id

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Join to get the team name.

SELECT query is need to look like this....

> "SELECT team_name FROM teams JOIN teams_members ON
>   teams.teams_id=teams_members.teams_id"

to get all row data from teams table use this query

> "SELECT * FROM teams JOIN teams_members ON
>   teams.teams_id=teams_members.teams_id"